# Return Certain JSON objects by using specialist attributes

Tags: jquery, ajax, json

I am trying to use a .json file to create a series of objects that are used on multiple pages across our site, and then pull them into different pages on the site using the getJSON function in Jquery. What I would like some help with is figuring out how to get only certain objects from my file, based on values that I pass to a special attribute within a div. 
I have most of the code down, but I seem to be missing something to get it to work.

Here is the div within the page, that I am using to pass the data keys I would like to get to the getJSON function as well as append the returned data to.

```
<div id="moreSolutions" boxes="revcyle ev ev_for_physicians"></div>
```

And here are a couple of objects from the .json file that I am pulling data from:

```
[   {
"divName":"ev",
"link":"/pages/our-solutions/t-systemev.php",
"class":"moreSolutionsDiv",
"class2":"moreSolutionsDivSubHead",
"id":"ev",
"span1":"<center><span class='h3'>EV™<br /></span></center>",
"span2":"<center>Easy, Effective, EDIS</center>"
}
}
,
{
"divName":"evForPhysiciansDiv",
"link":"/pages/our-solutions/ev_for_physicians.php",
"class":"moreSolutionsDiv",
"class2":"moreSolutionsDivSubHead",
"id":"evForPhysiciansDiv",
"span1":"<center><span class='h3'>EV™ <br />for physicians</span></center>",
"span2":"<center>Take back control of your documentation</center>"
}
]
```

And this is the jQuery that I am using to grab the content:

```
$("document").ready(function(){
var searchField = $('#moreSolutions').attr("boxes");
var searchArray = new Array;
searchArray = searchField.split(' ');  
$.getJSON('data.json', function(data) {
var output = "";
var index = 0;
$.each(data, function(key, val){
index ++; 
output += "<a href='"+val.link+"'>";                    
output += "<div class='"+val.class+"'>";
output += val.span1;
output += "<div id='"+val.id+"'></div>";
output += "<div class='"+val.class2+"'>";
output += val.span2;
output += "</div>";
output += "</div>";
output += "</a>";
});                 
$("#moreSolutions").html(output);       
});
```

});

I am able to do just about everything, including get the attributes from my div into an array, but I am having a hard time figuring out how to loop through the returned data to get the content I want. Ideally, my query would ask for all keys with a "divName" value, and then return all the data within that entire data set. I.E. IF I asked for the key "ev", i would get back the link, class, class2, id, span1 and span2 keys and values.
Thanks in advance for helping with that.

Answer (score 0):

[underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) has a bunch of useful functions for working with objects and arrays.

Once you have your JSON data, you can use the `_.filter` function to get just the objects that match a truth test.  The truth test is whether the object's `divName` property is in your list of search terms.  Once you have just the matches, you can use `_.each` to iterate over each object and construct your output.

```
$("document").ready(function(){
    var searchField = $('#moreSolutions').attr("boxes");
    var searchArray = searchField.split(' ');
    $.getJSON('temp.json', function(data) {
        var matches = _.filter(data, function(jsonObj) {
            return _.contains(searchArray, jsonObj.divName);
        });
        var output = "";
        _.each(matches, function(val) {
            output += "<a href='"+val.link+"'>";                    
            output += "<div class='"+val.class+"'>";
            output += val.span1;
            output += "<div id='"+val.id+"'></div>";
            output += "<div class='"+val.class2+"'>";
            output += val.span2;
            output += "</div>";
            output += "</div>";
            output += "</a>";
        });                 
        $("#moreSolutions").html(output);       
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi Kielni, thanks for the response. I did try a bunch of different variations of this code, but I couldn't get it to work. I am pretty new to .json, so what would really help is if you could attach a fully functional example of both the json file (however simple), as well as the jQuery that you use to get the data. Once I have that, and I know that it works, it's a lot easier for me to work backwards and figure out what is going on.

Comment: The above code works with the JSON you posted.  If it doesn't work for you, post what you tried, what you saw, and what you expected to see.

Comment: I added links to jQuery and underscore-min.js to the headers, and then used your code verbatim within an html page after the div called  <div id="moreSolutions" boxes="divName"></div>. The .json data I put into a file called temp.json within the same folder.

Comment: I don't get any data on my page, and even when I go to the console, I can't  see any returned data sets or arrays. If you would be willing to create a working example on your computer, zip it, and send it over to me, I would be very grateful, as this has been getting the better of me for a couple of weeks now. Thanks so much. 
Marc.

Comment: Open it in a debugger and (eg Firebug or Chrome Developer Tools), step through it, and trace what's going wrong.